# CSS code affecting what it is not supposed to be affecting

Tags: php, html, css

www.geo-village.com <- Live Example

Alright, so I have my main webpage's CSS and PHP file. i also include a navigation bar that is in a seperate PHP and CSS file. I have added a border for the navigation bar items. Why is the Login and Register buttons being affected? The login and register buttons are in the main html file and is does not have an id of #navbar which is why i am confused.

MAIN HTML FILE

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>GeoVillage - A Community</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id=header>
            <img id=logo src="/image/header.png" alt="GeoVillage Community" style="width:500px;height:64px;">
            <span id=logreg>
                <?php
                    if(isset($_SESSION['loggedon']) && $_SESSION['loggedon'] == true){
                        echo '<a href=/logout>
                            <img id=logout src="/image/logout.png" alt="Logout">
                            </a>';
                        if ($_SESSION['adminsts'] == admin || $_SESSION['adminsts'] == sadmin) {
                            echo '<a href=/admin>
                            <img id=admingears src="/image/admin.png" alt="Admin Panel">
                            </a>';
                        }
                    } else {
                        echo '<a href=/login>
                            <img id=login src="/image/login.png" alt="Login">
                            </a>';
                        echo '<a href=/login/register.php>
                            <img id=register src="/image/register.png" alt="Register">
                            </a>';
                    }
                ?>
            </span>
        </div>
        <?php
            //NAVIGATION BAR IMPORT
            echo '<div id=navbar>';
                include 'navbar.php';
            echo '</div>';
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS (MAIN FILE)

```
body {
    background-color: lightgrey;
    margin: 20px;
    margin-left: 200px;
    margin-right: 200px;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
#header{
    display:block;
}

#logreg{
    vertical-align: top;
    padding-top: 0px;
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
}

#logreg a {
    padding-right: 1px;
}
```

NAVBAR.PHP

```
    <?php
        session_start();
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="/navbarstyle.css">
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id=navbar>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href=/>Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href=/vatsim>VatSim Online Training</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>

navbar.css

#navbar {
    background-color: #33ccff;
    padding: 5px;
}

#navbar li, a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline;
    color: blue;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold; 
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding: 20px;
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid;
}

#navbar ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Had you done any proper error checking, you would have seen that `if ($_SESSION['adminsts'] == admin || $_SESSION['adminsts'] == sadmin)` would be throwing you warnings about undefined constants and most likely outputting before header.

Comment: Thats not an issue. Before adding borders, no errors and that isnt relavant to the problem. I have defined these in the SESSION.

Comment: oh, you think?! or is that pseudo code? (being a curveball).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are selecting *all* `<a>` tags in your document:

```
#navbar li, a {
    ....
}
```

To scope these styles to `<a>`'s within `#navbar` you need to remove the comma (`,`)

Comment: are you 100% of this answer? You missed something crucial in their code and I've outlined that in a comment up there. Edit: unless they threw us a curveball.

Comment: Errors in the PHP have nothing to do with CSS issue OP describes.

Comment: yeah I know, which is why I edited my comment above ;-)

Comment: Thanks turnip that worked. Fred, I was using that before an am getting no errors. I don't understand what you are saying about errors.

Comment: @Geocrafter This http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and applied to your code, in relation to `if ($_SESSION['adminsts'] == admin || $_SESSION['adminsts'] == sadmin)` as to what I said in comments above. If that's your real code and you've defined `admin` and `sadmin` as constants; fine. Otherwise, not quoting those would have thrown you undefined constants warnings/notices.

Comment: i have defined these values in my login page.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Guys, please take this to [Chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/). It has nothing to do with the original question. You are just creating unnecessary noise.